# Indentation in itemize

Tags: itemize

I want to use the itemize environment and follow each item with a description. I want the indentation to be normal for the description. Any way to make that work?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! (a) Why do you want to use `itemize` to create description lists and not `description`? (b) Could you please add a minimal code example of what you have (MWE)?

Comment: Simply because I am not aware that description is something that exists. I am new to everything related to Latex and pretty much it's the blind (me) leading the blind (also me :p). Just to indicate how much I am new to all this, i don't even know how to make terms related to Latex appear in a box with a different font and color and all.

Comment: If you don't know what an `MWE` is: [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/117727). For code blocks or any other text formatting, check the "help" link. It gives you a short intro to `markdown`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I correctly understand your question, you want to be able to print a line that is not indented and then continue with your indentation, like so:

```
- Item 1
Description of item 1
- Item 2
Description of item 2
```

With `itemize` this is easily achievable, just end the `itemize` environment, write your description and open a new one.

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item Item 1
\end{itemize}

Description of item 1

\begin{itemize}
    \item Item 2
\end{itemize}

Description of item 2
```

If you want to do the same thing with an enumeration, you should use the `enumitem` package. This package allows you, to resume the enumeration after a block of text outside the environment.

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Item 1
\end{enumerate}

Description of item 1

\begin{enumerate}[resume]
    \item Item 2
\end{enumerate}

Description of item 2
```

If you pass the option `[resume]` to the environment, it resumes the last enumeration, if you don't it begins a new enumeration.

---

#### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

    \section{Itemize}

    \begin{itemize}
        \item Item 1
    \end{itemize}

    \noindent Description of item 1

    \begin{itemize}
        \item Item 2
    \end{itemize}

    Description of item 2



    \section{Enumerate}

    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Item 1
    \end{enumerate}

    \noindent Description of item 1

    \begin{enumerate}[resume]
        \item Item 2
    \end{enumerate}

    Description of item 2

\end{document}
```

I also included the effect of the `\noindent` command.

---

### *This was not asked anymore:*

If you also want to make the indentation flush with the left margin (have the effect of `\noindent` on the `itemize` or `enumerate` environment), you can do that by adding the `leftmargin=*` option to the environments. This also requires the `enumitem` package.

#### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

    \section{Itemize}
    
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Indented item...
    \end{itemize}
    
    ... with an indented description
    
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Indented item...
    \end{itemize}
    
    \noindent ... with a non-indented description
    
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
        \item Non-indented item...
    \end{itemize}
    
    ... with an indented description
    
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
        \item Non-indented item...
    \end{itemize}
    
    \noindent ... with a non-indented description
    
    
    
    \section{Enumerate}
    
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Indented item...
    \end{enumerate}
    
    ... with an indented description
    
    \begin{enumerate}[resume]
        \item Indented item...
    \end{enumerate}
    
    \noindent ... with a non-indented description
    
    \begin{enumerate}[resume, leftmargin=*]
        \item Non-indented item...
    \end{enumerate}
    
    ... with an indented description
    
    \begin{enumerate}[resume, leftmargin=*]
        \item Non-indented item...
    \end{enumerate}
    
    \noindent ... with a non-indented description

\end{document}
```

With `\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=*}` in your preamble you can also globally set the indentation.

Comment: The OP requested itemize... (no resume necessary)

Comment: Correct, I'll modify my answer to include both.